# My trigger does not detect my player

Tags: unity, c#, collision-detection

My trigger does not detect my player.
My **Trigger.cs** file:

```
using UnityEngine;


public class Trigger : MonoBehaviour {

public Camera camera1;
public Camera camera2;
public GameObject panel;


 void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    camera1.enabled = false;
    camera2.enabled = true;
    panel.SetActive(true);
    Debug.Log ("Entered-");
}

 void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    camera2.enabled = false;
    camera1.enabled = true;
    panel.SetActive(false);
  
}
private void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
    {
        panel.SetActive(false);
        
    }
            }

}
```

[image: My player components. If I lower the box collider the player gets stuck in the floor.]

Where I can start troubleshooting te issue?

Object on which the trigger script is sitting on.
[image: Object on which the trigger script is sitting on.]

 **The solution:**
-- I created two colliders, and assigned one as a collider, the other (bigger) is a trigger. 
 -- I also had problems with the small triggers in the scene. The triggers were to small to be detected by my main player, althought
they detected my "sphere" player object

Comment: I added the inspector for the object on which the trigger is sitting on. Is it legal to add one  BoxCollider which has IsTrigger set to true, and one that has IsTrigger set to false?

Comment: Yes. The trigger collider will fire trigger events, while the non-trigger collider will handle physics collisions. Make sure they don't completely overlap though, or the non-trigger collider might prevent objects from ever reaching & tripping the trigger collider inside.

Comment: Which camera is your player? Have you set the proper camera to be tagged as player in the inspector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set `IsTrigger` to `true` on the `BoxCollider`.
If this isn't set, it indicated that the box collider is only used for physics.

If you are trying to fire code when two objects collide, you need to use `OnCollisionEnter`, `OnCollisionExit`, `OnCollisionStay`

See the following documentation for more information:

[Collider](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html)

[IsTrigger](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider-isTrigger.html)

Comment: I enabled it, but nothing happened. Also now my object won't now collide with my colliders. I edited my triggers and moved them up, so my player is being detected, but there is no collision with my colliders anymore.

Comment: Triggers are for detecting when another collider enters exits or stays inside the volume of the collider that is marked "IsTrigger". It will stop the collider from being used for collisions. See the updated answer momentarily